# How may I emulate a element with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Please see following code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="data_set" value="{&quot;contact_email&quot;:&quot;email@email.com&quot;,&quot;basic_pckg&quot;:&quot;pip&quot;}">

<a  class="actionButton" role="button" data-container="body" data-close-location="center" data-toggle="data_set" > click here </a>
```

I want change it to following:

```
<a  class="actionButton" role="button" onclick="myfoo();" > click here </a>
```

in my foo I want to emulate the basic  element
myfoo:

```
function myfoo()
{
    var xxx = '{"contact_email":"new_email@email.com","basic_pckg":"ok"}';
    
    document.getElementById("data_set").value = xxx;

var _a_link = document.createElement("a");
    
    
    _a_link.className= "actionButton";
    _a_link.setAttribute("role", "button");
    _a_link.setAttribute("data-close-location", "center");
    _a_link.setAttribute("data-container", "body");
    _a_link.setAttribute("data-toggle", "data_set");

    _a_link.click();
}
```

and it's not working. another function foo2:

```
function foo2()
{
//....
that.settings = tryParseJSON($('#data_set').val()); 
// contact_email == email@email.com
// instead of new_email@email.com
//...
}
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Parentless elements (elements not attached to the DOM) can't be clicked.

Comment: How can I attach it to DOM? By setting the ID to element?

Comment: Use one of [before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/before), [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after), [prepend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend), [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), and my favorite [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement).

Comment: I've added document.body.appendChild(_a_link); afetr  a_link declaration, but it still not works