# How can I add an element created in Javascript to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

```
const totalBill = document.querySelector(".total-bill");
let errorDiv = document.querySelector(".error");

function isValid(e) {
  if (totalBill.value.trim().length == 0) {
    let para = document.createElement("div");
    para.innerText = "Please enter the total amount of bill";
    // para.classList.add("bill-para");
    para.setAttribute('class', 'bill-error')
    console.log(para);
    errorDiv.innerHTML = para;
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="error">
            
        </div>
        <div class="box-container">
            <h1 class="heading">TIP CALCULATOR</h1>
            <form action="">
                <div class="box">
                    <label>How much was your bill?</label><br>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Total Bill" class="total-bill">
                </div>
            </form>
       </div>
```

So I am trying to add a div in div.error section and I want to add div named div.bill-error but whenever I am trying to replace the innerHTML and run the code. It shows me '[Object HTMLDivElement]' instead of "Please enter the total amount of bill". But in the console I see that the div is created. But it is not inserted inside

Can anyone tell me where is the problem and solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69177539/how-may-i-emulate-a-element-with-js#comment122276134_69177539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `errorDiv.appendChild(para);`, or, if you want to delete existing content in `errorDiv` first, then `errorDiv.textContent = ''; errorDiv.appendChild(para);`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, replace

```
 errorDiv.innerHTML = para;
```

with

```
errorDiv.append(para);
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried append also. But same happened.

Answer (score 0):

use `appendChild()` , I modified your code, here's the snipppet :

```js
const totalBill = document.querySelector(".total-bill");
let errorDiv = document.querySelector(".error");

function isValid(e) {
  if (totalBill.value.trim().length == 0) {
    let para = document.createElement("div");
    para.innerHTML = "Please enter the total amount of bill";
    // para.classList.add("bill-para");
    para.setAttribute('class', 'bill-error')
    errorDiv.appendChild(para);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="error">
            
        </div>
        <div class="box-container">
            <h1 class="heading">TIP CALCULATOR</h1>
            <form action="">
                <div class="box">
                    <label>How much was your bill?</label><br>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Total Bill" class="total-bill">
                </div>
                <button type="button" onclick="isValid();">Check</button>
            </form>
       </div>
```